# Appending a filename with slashes and other unsafe characters to the end of a file NSURL?

Tags: cocoa, uikit, nsurl

I have an `NSURL` pointing to a directory. I also have the name of a file with all sorts of crazy characters. (Forward slashes, backward slashes, periods, etc.) I want to append the name of my file to my URL to create a file path. Unfortunately, if I use the standard `URLByAppendingPathComponent:` style methods, my crazy filename isn't correctly escaped! For example, the `NSURL` treats any forward slashes as path separators, whereas I want to percent-encode them with the rest of the filename. However, if I pre-percent-encode my filename, `NSURL` doubly-encodes the percent signs, leading to garbage for my filename.

What's the correct and safe way to perform this task?

Comment: It would be useful if you could include an example of the filenames that are giving you trouble in your question. Also, have you had a look at the ``NSString`` methods that deal with percent encoding? Navigate over to that page and do a search for *percent* - there are a few methods there that might help.

Comment: An example filename would be "/test/12.3?" — technically legal but not very pretty. I tried using the percent encoding methods, but unfortunately I haven't figured out the correct way to get a functioning file:// URL from an existing NSURL and a percent-encoded filename. There doesn't seem to be a way to pass an already-encoded path component to an NSURL — it always re-encodes the percent signs. I tried manually merging my filename with the NSURL's absoluteString, but it didn't work for some reason.